# How to display large double numbers without scientific notation in C?

Tags: c, printf, double, format-specifiers

How can I display a double like

```
5000683
```

Instead of `5.000683e6` in C?

I have tried `%d`, `%g` and `%f`, but to no avail.

Comment: [`%f`: no scientific notation](http://ideone.com/rukF3A). You can specify the [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) if you don't want digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `%f` works just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double d = 5000683;
  printf("%f\n", d);
  printf("%.0f\n", d);

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this code will be

```
5000683.000000
5000683
```

The second `printf()` statement sets the precision to 0 (by prefixing `f` with `.0`) to avoid any digits after the decimal point.